# Relocate the .pst and .ost from Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

Currently, Outlook is storing my `.pst` file in `C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook` but I would much rather it be placed elsewhere (`C:\` is an SSD, and I have a `D:\` that is a regular drive, and I would much rather than be used in stead).

How can I move the file permanently?

Comment: Did you tried [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2752583)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the ost-file in Outlook 2013 is no longer possible via the interface in Outlook. Instead, the quickest way to go would be to create Symbolic Links instead.

With a Symbolic Link, you’d be creating a “pseudo file” which is only a pointer to the actual file. This differs from a shortcut as a shortcut is actually a link-file whereas a Symbolic Link will retain the original file name.

This may sound all very complex, but the actual process is quite easy and very effective. You’ll find step-by-step instructions in the guide: [Moving an IMAP pst-file or Hotmail ost-file](http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/movingimappsthotmailost.htm).

Note: Don’t place the ost-file on a network share. This is unsupported and it would defeat the purpose of enabling Cached Exchange Mode. The ost-file should reside on an internal drive.

([source](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/463))

Comment: Can symlinks be to other drives, or are they limited in that regard?

Comment: They can be used across drives - see the linked article.

Comment: note using Symbolic Link's in Windows 10 will cause Outlook 2013 to not be able to access the account settings page. Just a heads up as I tried that solution to this problem and spent ages trying to figure out why I could access mail but the account information page kept saying the account was being migrated but never completed. The sym link was the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-an-outlook-data-file-pst-to-different-folder-HA010378229.aspx

You shouldn't need to move the .OST as that is your Windows profile mail settings, and shouldn't be affected by moving your .PST

Comment: I have moved my .PST, but my .OST files remain stubborn. How can I force them to move as well?

Comment: Why are you needing to move the .OST -- Did something break when you moved the .PST? 

It's simply your mail setup for your Windows profile. If you want to delete it and recreate it, you can go to Control Panel > Mail > Delete the mail setup associated with your Windows profile. Then the next time you start Exchange it will recreate a new mail profile (and new .OST). ** Keep in mind this will get rid of your specific mail setup**

Comment: The OST files are >200 MB, and I want them to move to the non-SSD drive. Trying now

Comment: Looks like you can move the OST in the same place (Ctrl Panel > Mail):
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/move-an-offline-outlook-data-file-ost-HA010378297.aspx

Comment: It seems that that option is grayed out (if it matters, this is for an IMAP account).

Even creating a new account using a `.pst` file on the other drive does not work.